# Types, Vector and Sealed Class Scala

Tags: scala, vector, jena

I have the following code in a trait on SCALA,

```
trait example {
  type Schema = Vector[String] //Variable Names

  sealed abstract class Value;
  case class URI(name: Node) extends Value
  case class Literal(value: Node) extends Value
  case class BlankNode(name: Node) extends Value
  case class Variable(name: Node) extends Value

  type Fields = Vector[Value] //vector of values
```

Then, I am filling this objects using the element visitor from apache Jena in other class as follow:

```
class interpreter (q:Query) extends SPARQLInterpreter {
  //val Fields = Vector[Value]
  ElementWalker.walk(q.getQueryPattern(),

    new ElementVisitorBase() {

      override def visit(el: ElementPathBlock) {

        val triples: util.Iterator[TriplePath] = el.patternElts
        while (triples.hasNext()) {
          val aux1: Triple = triples.next().asTriple()
          val u:Value = URI(aux1.getSubject())
          val b:Value = BlankNode(aux1.getPredicate)
          val l:Value = Literal(aux1.getObject()) 
        }
      }
    })
```

Then, my question is how I should fill the Fields type declare on the trait, like Fields(u,b,l) because is a vector, but the compiler detects an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write `Fields(u,b,l)` because there is no object `Fields`

What you could do is `val fields: Fields = Vector(u, b, l)`  which creates a value names fields whose type is Vector[Value] and assigning something to it.

`type` is used to create a type alias which only affects the names of types.  `type Fields = Vector[Value]` creates a new name for `Vector[Value]` and the types `Fields` and `Vector[Value]` can now be used interchangeably because they mean the same thing.

What this doesn't do is create a new name for the `Vector` object, so you can't refer to it using the name Fields.

Comment: I'll just add that you can also declare `val Fields = Vector` together with `type Fields` and enable `Fields(u, b, l)` etc.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov very true, but that has some downsides like being able to then say `Fields(1,2,3,4)` to create a `Vector[Int]` which doesn't conform to the type `Fields` which could be misleading.

Comment: True. You can avoid this concern by using `object Fields { def apply(fields: String*): Fields = Vector(fields: _*) }` instead (add other desired methods to taste).